# Static_dir working locally on Development sever not in Production - PHP GAE 1.8.2

Tags: php, google-app-engine, stylesheet, production-environment, app.yaml

I am getting the following error from the logs in the production server on PHP version of GAE

```
Static file referenced by handler not found: stylesheets/IT%20Issue/style.css
Static file referenced by handler not found: scripts/IT%20Issue/script.js
Static file referenced by handler not found: scripts/IT%20Issue/jquery.min.js
```

But I do not get these errors when I run them locally using

```
D:\Python\python.exe D:/google_appengine_1.8.2/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=D:\PHP\php-cgi.exe .
```

Here is part my app.yaml file

```
handlers:
- url: /stylesheets/
  static_dir: stylesheets/

- url: /images/
  static_dir: images/

- url: /scripts/
  static_dir: scripts/
```

And here is part of the php file that calls these files.

```
<?php
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Secured page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/IT Issue/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/IT Issue/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/IT Issue/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
```

I did a few searches here and someone said out caps may allow to run locally but not in production.
Here is my actual file locations. I do not think I have the case sensitive problem.

```
"D:\Google_PHP\stylesheets\IT Issue\style.css"
"D:\Google_PHP\scripts\IT Issue\script.js"
"D:\Google_PHP\scripts\IT Issue\jquery.min.js"
```

I don't think I did anything wrong. But I would like to have a second opinion or would like to be corrected so I can keep learning this stuff.

Comment: did you try it without the space in the directory name "IT Issue" ?

Comment: Changing it to IT_Issue seems to work but I don't think that would be a good fix. It would be better if the paths could resolve even if there were spaces in a static directory name. I had a few lines to change but if bigger projects were to be moved this would mean going through every line an cross checking. Also there is no mention of space being issue in any of the documentation. Can Google fix this @StuartLangley ?

Comment: file an issue in the tracker

Comment: Done. Issue number  9681.  
I will use the work around till then not sure when I will reach the wall though. Thanks Stuart.